# Structural Break Test in Eviews

Tags: time-series, structural-change, eviews

My data set contains 55 data points. I want to run a structural break tests. I am using Eviews 8 and I know that I am supposed to estimate an equation using **Quick->Estimate**, then once it is estimated, click on **View->Structural Diagnostics->Multiple Breakpoint test**.
However I am confused as to which equation should i estimate before knowing the break date?

Answer (score 1):

First look at the plot of your time series data to have an idea about break point.

- If there seems to be a single structural break (also require literature support), you can test it by using '**Chow breakpoint test**' and if there seems to be multiple structural breaks (also require literature support), you can test the exact breakpoint by using '**Bai-Perron muliple breakpoint test**'.

In Eviews, the following steps can be followed:

- Select data - view - graph - basic graph - line & symbol - OK
- Visualize, if there is any break point. At what time is it present (rough estimate)
- quick - estimate equation - enter your equation - Ok
- View - stability diagnostic - Chow breakpoint test (if single break) - enter date (which you've taken from graph) - click ok - interpret the result

  - View - stability diagnostic - multiple breakpoint test (if more than one break) - select method, maximum breaks(which you've taken from graph), trimming % and sig level as per your requirement - click ok - interpret the result